# Share multiple files of Document Library programatically

Tags: document-library, client-object-model, rest, api

I want to share multiple files from `Document Library` programatically or any other way using `Client Object model` or `REST API`.

Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by share.. grant permissions?? or send files ?

Comment: We have option "Share" in Document Library under Files Tab

Comment: Are you in 2013 or sharepoint online?

Answer (score 1):

To share a single document using REST API , you can use the below code:

To share multiple document, you can call the below code in a for loop and passing parameters:

```
function shareDocument() {
var restSource = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.Sharing.DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo";       
 $.ajax(
 {
     'url': restSource,
     'method': 'POST',
     'data': JSON.stringify({
         'resourceAddress': _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/Shared Documents/Document.pdf',
         'userRoleAssignments': [{
             '__metadata': {
                 'type': 'SP.Sharing.UserRoleAssignment'
             },
            //The Role property represents which permission you are assigning. 1 =  View, 2 =  Edit, 3 = Owner, 0 = None
             'Role': 1, 
             'UserId': 'Gautam Sheth' 
         }],
         'validateExistingPermissions': false,
         'additiveMode': true,
         'sendServerManagedNotification': false,
         'customMessage': "Document has been shared with you",
         'includeAnonymousLinksInNotification': false
     }),
     'headers': {
         'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
         'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
         'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
     },
     'success': function (data) {
         var d = data;
     },
     'error': function (err) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(err));
     }
 }
 );  }
```

To share it with a site group and another user, you can use it as below:

```
function shareDocument()
{
    var restSource = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.Sharing.DocumentSharingManager.UpdateDocumentSharingInfo"; 

    $.ajax(
    {
        'url': restSource,
        'method': 'POST',
        'data': JSON.stringify({
            'resourceAddress': _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/Shared Documents/Document.pdf',
            'userRoleAssignments': [{
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.Sharing.UserRoleAssignment'
                },
                'Role': 1,
                'UserId': 'Site Members'
            },
            {
                '__metadata': {
                    'type': 'SP.Sharing.UserRoleAssignment'
                },
                'Role': 1,
                'UserId': 'Gautam Sheth'
            }],
            'validateExistingPermissions': false,
            'additiveMode': true,
            'sendServerManagedNotification': false,
            'customMessage': "Document has been shared with you",
            'includeAnonymousLinksInNotification': false
        }),
        'headers': {
            'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
            'X-RequestDigest': $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
        },
        'success': function (data) {
            var d = data;
        },
        'error': function (err) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    }
    ); 
}
```